# Accessing a variable from the script in the HTML code?

Tags: python, template-engine, bottle

I am using the Bottle framework (also using Beaker for sessions) for Python and am having trouble accessing a variable from the script in the HTML code. The following is the Python script:

```
import os, MySQLdb, hashlib, random, markdown2
import beaker.middleware
import bottle
from bottle import run, route, post, get, request, abort, template, hook, app, view

@post('/submit')
def submit():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user="root", passwd="blkFDF94alkf", db="_pCMS")
    query = db.cursor()

    user = request.forms.get('credentials.username')
    username = MySQLdb.escape_string(user)
    request.session['username'] = username
    passw = request.forms.get('credentials.password')
    pass_w = MySQLdb.escape_string(passw)
    passw2 = str(pass_w)
    password = hashlib.md5(passw2).hexdigest()
    user_name = request.session['username']


    if username >= 2 and password >= 6:
        if True:
            ugh = query.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'" % (username, password))
            db.commit()
            return me()
    else:
        return index()
```

I doubt the code above needs to be explained since all I need to know is how to access the variable user_name in that function of that Python script on the HTML code below. This is what I have of the HTML:

me.tpl:

```
<div class="label">Name:</div>
    %if len(user_name) >= 2:
        <div class="content">{{user_name}}</div>
    %end
</div>
```

Is that the correct way to access the variable user_name? It isn't working that way because it's giving me the following error:

```
NameError: name 'user_name' is not defined
```

What me() and index() do:

```
@route('/')
@route('/index')
@view('index.tpl')
def index():
    index = { 'index' : _index()}
    return index

def _index():
    return 't'


@get('/me')
@view('me.tpl')
def me():
    me = { 'me' : _me()}
    return me

def _me():
    return 't'
```

Comment: What do `me()` and `index()` do?

Comment: @RayToal they simply point to other functions that call the templates. I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your `me` view should take a `user_name` parameter and inject it in the template:

```
@get('/me')
@view('me.tpl')
def me(user_name):
    me = { 
        'me': _me(),
        'user_name': user_name
    }
    return me
```